# Sort String as double

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to sort my file contents as double in the ascending order

My input file contains for example these lines:

```
105 350 4.41386e-06 4.41386e-06 
115 300 4.58965e-06 4.58965e-06 
15  150 1.6457e-06  1.6457e-06  
255 550 5.33661e-05 5.33661e-05 
25  150 3.21907e-06 3.21907e-06 
35  550 2.57952e-05 2.57952e-05 
45  150 1.78332e-06 1.78332e-06
```

And i want my output file to have them as following:

```
15  150 1.6457e-06  1.6457e-06  
25  150 3.21907e-06 3.21907e-06 
35  550 2.57952e-05 2.57952e-05 
45  150 1.78332e-06 1.78332e-06 
105 350 4.41386e-06 4.41386e-06 
115 300 4.58965e-06 4.58965e-06 
255 550 5.33661e-05 5.33661e-05
```

Since i am just a beginner in C++ coding, if have tried these line to do that task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream textfile( "Limit.txt" );
    std::string text_input;
    std::vector< std::string > sort_vec;
    std::ofstream outfile1;
    TString outfile_name1 = "Limits.txt";
    if ( textfile.is_open() )
    {
        outfile1.open( outfile_name1 );

        while ( std::getline( textfile,text_input ) )
        {  
            sort_vec.push_back(text_input);
        }

        textfile.close();
    }

    std::sort( std::begin( sort_vec ), std::end( sort_vec ), std::less<string>() );
    
    for ( const auto & e : sort_vec )
    {
        outfile1 << e << "\n";
    }

    outfile1.close();
}
```

But I could not get the results that I want.

Could please help me through.

Comment: Do you succeed to extract double from given lines?

Comment: @SOUMAIMIZainab *I am trying to sort my file contents as double in the ascending order* -- It looks like you are using the first column of numbers to sort on, and they seem to be all integers, not double.

Comment: @Jarod42 No i don't actually.

Comment: Some free formatting advice given by means of an edit. Have a look at what I changed. Also, what is `TString`? Also, in case this is an actual problem you need to solve (in whatever language) and not just a programming practice, consider `man sort`. ;-)

Comment: This question is still unclear. Typically, when you want to sort a line with multiple fields, you want to sort the line by the first field. If that is a tie, you want to sort it by the second field, etcetera.

Comment: @DevSolar thank you so much. TString is a class in ROOT CERN framework for declaring a string; it has the same job as std:string

Comment: @SOUMAIMIZainab -- What if there are two or more lines that start with `15`?  As was pointed out, you need to specify the exact sorting criteria to us before anyone can answer your question sufficiently.  It is the sorting criteria that is basically what any potential answer will be written to follow.

Comment: So first step would be to extract values from the line, then `std::sort(std::begin(sort_vec), std::end(sort_vec), [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs){ return extract_field_double(lhs) < extract_field_double(rhs); });`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Way too complex. Extract to a `std::tuple<int, int, double, double>`. That will sort straight away.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i want to attach my input file but i don't know how. And indeed, there are many lines starting with "15".

Comment: @MSalters: Unclear for me the expected fields used for sorting. (OP uses `double` and I consider first 2 fields as integer so not used for sorting, but after seeing expected output you might have right).

Comment: @SOUMAIMIZainab -- Sorting criteria doesn't require us to look at the file.  The sorting criteria should have been given to you in detail.  How else would you know how to write your sorting code if you don't know the exact sorting criteria?  It isn't up to one of us to tell you what the criteria is by looking at the file, you have to tell us.  If you are not sure, go back to your teacher (or whoever gave you this assignment) and have them clarify what the criteria is.

Comment: I struggle to understand why this doesn't work as is. `std::less<std::string>()` is supposed to sort lexicographically the strings, which would give the expected results, but it seems that `std::sort()` is a no-op here for a strange reason...

Comment: i want to sort  the lines in a way to start from 15 to 255 knowing that i have several lines starting with "15" and others starting with "25" and so on.

Comment: @Fareanor: The problem is that lexiographically, 1 sorts before 2, so 105 sorts between 10 and 11.

Comment: @MSalters Oh right, I'm so stupid XD

Comment: @SOUMAIMIZainab -- So which "15" goes before the other "15"?  Each line contains additional columns.   Are they going to be used as tie-breakers?  All of this information should have been given out to you.

Comment: yes, that is why i wanted to attach my input file. each "15" line for example is having in the second column [150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750] and this is the same for the others but there are other lines starting from 350 to 750 in the 2nd column

Comment: @SOUMAIMIZainab -- Again, we do not need to look at the file.  This is what we are looking for you to describe:  "My file consists of 4 columns of data.  They are supposed to be sorted in ascending, hierarchical order.  For example, if the same value occurs in the first column, then sort in ascending order on the second column.  Ties in the second column means that the sort is done on the third column, etc." -- That is what we would like to see worded.  Note that it did not take for me to upload a file.

Comment: pardon me, i could not formulate my needs this way since i am trying to develop my english as well as my coding. Thank you for making it that simple. Indeed, i have the same value occurs in the first column, and i want to sort in ascending order on the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of spaces and different length of data in each line, the lexicographic sorting of lines as strings may produce unexpected results or be totally wrong.

Therefore I would recommend to split the lines into it 4 parts, which is very simple using normal IO-extract-functionality using the `>>` operator.

The data of one row can be stored in a struct. That is somehow intuitive, readable and understandable. For storing the whole list, we can use a `std::vector` of such a struct.

Instead of using a struct, we can also use a `std::tuple` as proposed by Jarod42. A `std::tuple` has comparison operators, which allow ultra simple sorting of one row later.

Anyway. Let us start with a struct, which has additional possibilities, as shown later.

1. Define the struct
2. Open the file and check, if it could be opened
3. Define a `std::vector` of the above struct
4. Create a temporary instance of a struct, te be able to read data into it
5. In a loop, extract data from the file and store in struct-elements
6. Push back each just read data into the `vector` (we will call it database)
7. Sort with a lambda expression to have full control on how things will be sorted
8. Show result to the user

This can be coded in many ways. Look at on potential example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

struct Data {
    int i1{};
    int i2{};
    double d1{};
    double d2{};
};

int main() {

    // Open the source textfile and check, if it could be opened
    std::ifstream textfile("Limit.txt");
    if (textfile) {

        // Here we will store all data
        std::vector<Data> database{};

        // Temporary storage for 1 line
        Data data{};

        // Read all lines and add data to the database
        while (textfile >> data.i1 >> data.i2 >> data.d1 >> data.d2)
            database.push_back(data);

        // Sort database and use a lambda to do it as wished
        std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), [](const Data& d1, const Data& d2) {
            return d1.i1 == d2.i1 ? (d1.i2 == d2.i2 ? (d1.d1 == d2.d1 ? d1.d2 < d2.d1 : d1.d1 < d2.d1) : d1.i2 < d2.i2) : d1.i1 < d2.i1; });

        // Debug output
        for (const Data& d : database)
            std::cout << std::left << std::setw(4) << d.i1 << std::setw(4) << d.i2 << std::setw(12) << d.d1 << d.d2 << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error! Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```

But that is not all.

As you know, C++ is an object oriented language. And we can store data together with functions, operating on this data, in a struct (a struct is a class).

So, we can add input and output functions and the less than operator that is needed for sorting.

Then the main function will be significantly simpler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

struct Data {
    int i1{};
    int i2{};
    double d1{};
    double d2{};

    // Methods / operators
    // Input
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Data& data) {
        return is >> data.i1 >> data.i2 >> data.d1 >> data.d2;
    }
    // Output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Data& d) {
        return os << std::left << std::setw(4) << d.i1 << std::setw(4)
            << d.i2 << std::setw(12) << d.d1 << d.d2;
    }
    // Comparison
    bool operator < (const Data& other) {
        return i1 == other.i1 ? (i2 == other.i2 ? (d1 == other.d1 ? d2 < other.d1 : d1 < other.d1) : i2 < other.i2) : i1 < other.i1;
    }

};

int main() {

    // Open the source textfile and check, if it could be opened
    std::ifstream textfile("Limit.txt");
    if (textfile) {

        // Here we will store all data
        std::vector<Data> database{};

        // Temporary storage for 1 line
        Data data{};

        // Read all lines and add data to the database
        while (textfile >> data)
            database.push_back(data);

        // Sort database
        std::sort(database.begin(), database.end());

        // Debug output
        for (const Data& d : database)
            std::cout << d << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error! Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```

Advantage: Understandable and simple. Good control for sorting.
Disadvantage: Complex sorting criteria

Answer (score 1):

The issue here, as pointed out in comments, is that `std::less<std::string>` sorts your strings lexicographically (i.e. the same order as it would appear in a dictionary).

This is not the intended behaviour since the sort will be then performed character by character and not value by value.

To achieve the correct behaviour, you need to make a custom comparator that will extract the `double` value to perform the sorting based on it.

For example (using a lambda):

```
std::sort(sort_vec.begin(), sort_vec.end(), [](const std::string & lhs, const std::string & rhs){
    double ld, rd;
    std::stringstream{lhs} >> ld;
    std::stringstream{rhs} >> rd;

    return ld < rd;
});
```

And it would do the trick ([live example here](https://godbolt.org/z/s168f8sxv))

Comment: if the number of entries is considerably large then it is more efficient to first transform to double then sort. The comparator is called `O(N logN)` times , but only `N` transformations are required. (and the double isnt the first entry in the file)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Oh you're absolutely right, it would prevent to perform the conversion every time a comparison occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a hierarchical sort based on the columns from left-to-right, there are multiple ways to do this using `std::sort`.

One way is to read in the values into a [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and apply `std::sort` on a vector of these tuples.  The tuple class will automatically do a [lexicographical compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp), from left-to-right, of the tuple's components.

The `std::tuple<int, int, double, double>` basically mimics one line of your data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>

std::string test = 
"105 350 4.41386e-06 4.41386e-06\n"
"115 300 4.58965e-06 4.58965e-06\n" 
"15  150 1.6457e-06  1.6457e-06\n"  
"255 550 5.33661e-05 5.33661e-05\n" 
"25  150 3.21907e-06 3.21907e-06\n" 
"35  550 2.57952e-05 2.57952e-05\n" 
"45  150 1.78332e-06 1.78332e-06\n"
"105 35  4.41386e-06 4.41386e-06\n" 
"115 300 4.58965e-06 4.58965e-09\n" 
"15  150 1.6457e-04  1.6457e-04\n"  
"255 550 5.33661e-05 5.33661e-02";


using DataLine = std::tuple<int, int, double, double>;
using VectorDataLine = std::vector<DataLine>;

int main()
{
    std::istringstream textfile(test);
    VectorDataLine sort_vec;
    DataLine data_line;
    while ( textfile >> std::get<0>(data_line) >> 
                        std::get<1>(data_line) >> 
                        std::get<2>(data_line) >> 
                        std::get<3>(data_line)) 
    {  
       sort_vec.push_back(data_line);
    }
    std::sort( std::begin( sort_vec ), std::end( sort_vec ));

    for ( const auto & e : sort_vec )
    {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(e) << ' ' <<
                     std::get<1>(e) << ' ' << 
                     std::get<2>(e) << ' ' << 
                     std::get<3>(e)  << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
15 150 1.6457e-06 1.6457e-06
15 150 0.00016457 0.00016457
25 150 3.21907e-06 3.21907e-06
35 550 2.57952e-05 2.57952e-05
45 150 1.78332e-06 1.78332e-06
105 35 4.41386e-06 4.41386e-06
105 350 4.41386e-06 4.41386e-06
115 300 4.58965e-06 4.58965e-09
115 300 4.58965e-06 4.58965e-06
255 550 5.33661e-05 5.33661e-05
255 550 5.33661e-05 0.0533661
```